# PHP - Add 'meta' tag to all pages loading the script, and this script is outside 'head' tag

Tags: php, html, favicon, meta

I need to add a `meta` tag to all files of a website, so I thought about adding that `meta` tag by PHP code, within *header.php*, *menu.php* or *footer.php*; something like:

```
<?php addToHeadTag("Meta: favicon='./img/favicon.ico'"); ?>
```

It has a lot of files and manually changing each file is out of hand.

P.S.: All possible files in which I could include that code are outside `head`.

Comment: That is *so* not what the [`header()`](http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function does. Stop that immediately.

Comment: That's right. I changed the name of the imagined function to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can place an include file wherever you like in your code. Though that really has nothing to do with the problem at hand.

You should not be using `header()` for this. `header()` provides the client browser with meta information on the http response as a whole.

Take a look at this link for usage information on favicons:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon

In most cases you can just place the favicon.ico in your web root and the browser will pick it up automatically without any markup at all.  You can also use a `<link>` element.

Comment: Gonna try putting the favicon.ico in the web root after changing my client's domain (I'm using another one temporarily, so the favicon would be this domain's root favicon, right?)